# NHibernate CreateSQLQuery -> Dictionary<int, int>

Tags: nhibernate

I tend to use something like this:

```
return NHibernateSession.Current.CreateSQLQuery
(
@"
    some sql
"
)
.SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(someviewmodel)))
.List<someviewmodel>();
```

to map my sql output to a viewmodel. Is it quite straightforward to achieve the same mapping to a  Dictionary whilst using CreateSQLQuery which spews out two int columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would basically need to create your own transformer and specify it in your `SetResultTransformer` call.

It might look something like this:

```
public class CustomDictionaryTransformer : IResultTransformer
{
    public object TransformTuple(object[] tuple, string[] aliases)
    {
        KeyValuePair<int, int> result = new KeyValuePair<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.Length; i++)
        {
            string alias = aliases[i];
                            var val = new KeyValuePair<int, int>();
                            if (alias == "key") result.Key = (int)tuple[i];
                            else result.Value = (int)tuple[i];
        }

        return result;
    }

    public IList TransformList(IList collection)
    {
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks more complicated than writing a viewmodel with 2 ints, which I have done for the time being. Thanks anyway.